# How to run two different apps on the same domain using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-hosting

I have a Rails app at `example.com`, which is a Heroku app running under that domain. However, the marketing team would like something more dynamic to use to change the material on the main landing page.

My questions therefore are:

- Can I run a different system than Rails under the same domain (`example.com` is one system, `example.com/*` is the old Rails app)
- Can those 2 systems be in the same Ruby app?
- Can those 2 systems be in different languages (different Heroku apps)

I've done these kinds of setups on custom servers. Just wandering whether it's possible to do this on Heroku.

Comment: You could do this by standing up a reverse proxy dynamo in Heroku: https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/

It'd be easier to use a service for this though, like a CDN or https://routepath.app (disclaimer: I made Routepath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Heroku allows to associate zero or more custom domains to the same app, but it's not possible to associate two apps with the same domain and somehow split the routing.

It's also very hard to have two different applications co-existing under the same umbrella. You can create more rack-based applications inside the same project and mount them under the same Rails router (for instance you can mount a Sinatra or Lotus application at a specific path in a Rails project).

You cannot write the apps in two different languages, because it's not possible to build a single Heroku app with two different buildpacks. Well, in theory, you can write your own buildpack... but it's not trivial.

The only viable solution is to have more Rack-based applications mounted under the same Rails or Rack router (you can have N Rack applications, 1 Rails and N Rack, but it's hardly possible to have N Rails).

Comment: that's not true anymore, heroku now supports using multiple buildpacks https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app