# Multiple Heroku apps on the same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku and one of its paths must be connected to another Heroku app dedicated to a blog.

The objective is to use a path of the main website to reach the blog, keeping the original domain and avoiding the usage of different subdomains, this is a must due to SEO requirements.

Here the idea:

- [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) -> app1
- [www.site.com/blog](http://www.site.com/blog) -> app2 (blog)
- [www.site.com/blog/articles/xxx](http://www.site.com/blog/articles/xxx) -> article in app2 (blog)

Both the websites are developed in Ruby on Rails and hosted on Heroku. The path structure should be complete to be Google-friendly.

I've found some possible duplicates of this, but they are very old and related to deprecated plugins and gems not working at the moment:

1. [How to run two different apps on the same domain using heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557078/how-to-run-two-different-apps-on-the-same-domain-using-heroku)

   The first comment links to [this article](https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/) based on Docker Toolbox that is obsolete at the moment and also to [routepath.app](http://routepath.app) (broken link)
2. [Multiple Heroku apps on a single domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119164/multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain)

   This suggests the usage of the gem "rack-reverse-proxy". The docs clearly says that is not for production systems, and it seems no longer maintained. This duplicate also links to [this article](http://pivotallabs.com/migrating-from-a-single-rails-app-to-a-suite-of-rails-engines/), but it is a broken link.

Comment: It might be better to ask about a specific problem you've had with implementing the existing duplicates, or at least linking them with commentary - a reverse proxy is still a way to do this kind of thing, having one app that sends traffic out to two others as relevant.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. 
I have added what I found as potential duplicates in my post. I haven a real specific problem as I would like to find the best idea to do proceed.
It seems that reverse proxying is poorly documented on heroku and I think that only main guidelines on this should be useful for me and other users.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Convert the 2nd application to a [rails engine](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)
2. [Reverse proxy to the 2nd application](https://github.com/axsuul/rails-reverse-proxy)
3. Configure the 1st application to have a 2nd database, using the database from the 2nd application as a read-only [Rails Multiple Databases](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) (**I would choose this option**)

The last option allows you to keep your 2nd application as-is for editing and whatever it already does. You can redirect production viewing to the 1st application.

Comment: Thank you Blair, I never thought about engines for this. I'm now trying to understand how to use engine as an app, I'm really noob with rails engines. 
At the moment I have to create a new app and that will became a complete and a very complex blog website. 
How I can transform an app into engine? and also, has an engine all the funcionalities of a complete rails 7 app? I need webpack, frontend, full compatibility with active_admin, devise and the typical complete sets of rails modern gems

Comment: HI @RobertoBobBowldee thats the hardest option. Why not use option 3 if they're both on heroku?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find the time to test the last option. I used the gem rails-reverse-proxy, I saw it working but I lose the full url after reaching the url www.site.com/blog (it becomes immediately blog.site.com). Unfortunately I didn't found the way to get the gem working as per my initial question.
The last chance was to create a series of API in the first app to get data from the the second app, it is more time consuming, but still doable.
Thank you very much, I let you know!

Comment: yeah there is no "simple" way to accomplish what you want to do.